# mql5 error when drawing rectangle at specific candle location

Tags: mql5, drawrectangle, createobject, expert-advisor

I am trying to draw a rectangle starting at the gap when theres an FVG and have one of my curly brackets in the wrong place as its telling me i cant have my if statements in the global scope.

i need to be able to draw a rectangle when there is a gap between the candle 3 high and candle 1 low
or candle 3 low and candle 1 high

````
//A - Candle 3's low is higher than candle 1's high so there is a gap which needs to have a rectangle drawn there
//B - Candles 3's high is lower than candle 1's low so there is a gap which needs to have a rectangle drawn there

//define Candle OHLC Prices
  double CLow = PRICE_LOW;
  double CHigh = PRICE_HIGH;
  double COpen = PRICE_OPEN;
  double CClose = PRICE_CLOSE;

//define Bull and Bear Candles
  double Bull = PRICE_OPEN<PRICE_CLOSE;
  double Bear = PRICE_OPEN>PRICE_CLOSE;
  
  // Create variable for Highs and Lows for A or B Scenario
  int FVGHigh,FVGLow;
  
  // create array for Candle Highs and Lows
  double High[],Low[];
  
  // sort arrays downwards from the current candle
  ArraySetAsSeries(High,true);
  ArraySetAsSeries(Low,true);
 
  //Fill arrays with data for FVGs for 3 candles for FVG idenitification
  CopyHigh(_Symbol,_Period,0,3,High);
  CopyLow(_Symbol,_Period,0,3,Low); 
  
  //calculate the high and lows for the FVGs
  FVGHigh = ArrayMaximum(High,0,3);     // uses data for the last 3 candles
  FVGLow = ArrayMaximum(Low,0,3);       // uses data for the last 3 candles

  //Create an array for prices and sort it from current to oldest candles
  MqlRates Price[];
  ArraySetAsSeries(Price,true);
  
  //Copy price data into the array
  int Data=CopyRates(_Symbol,_Period,0,Bars(_Symbol,_Period),Price);
  
  // delete any previous rectangles
  ObjectDelete(_Symbol,"Rectangle");
  }
  
  // if candle 3 is a bear and candle 2 and candle 1 are both bulls.. and if there is a gap 
  if(Bear[3] and Bull[2] and Bull[1] and CHigh[3]<CLow[1]){
  
  //create the new rectangle using candle3s low, starting at candle 2, using candle 1s high and ending at candle 0
  ObjectCreate(_Symbol,"Rectangle",OBJ_RECTANGLE,0,Price[2].time,Price[FVGHigh].High[3],Price[0].time,Price[FVGLow].CLow[1]);

  //set Object line color
  ObjectSetInteger(0,"Rectangle",OBJPROP_COLOR,clrLime);
  
  //Set the Object fill color
  ObjectSetInteger(0,"Rectangle",OBJPROP_FILL,clrLime);
   }    //bracket that causes alot of errors if it isnt there

  //check if we have a Bull FVG
  // if candle 3 is a Bull and candle 2 and candle 1 are both bears.. and if there is a gap 
  if(Bull[3] and Bear[2] and Bear[2] and Low[3] > High[1]){
  
  //create the new rectangle using candle3s high, starting at candle 2, using candle 1s low and ending at candle 0
  ObjectCreate(_Symbol,"Rectangle",OBJ_RECTANGLE,0,Price[2].time,Price[FVGLow].CLow[3],Price[0].time,Price[FVGHigh].CHigh[1]);

  //set Object line color
  ObjectSetInteger(0,"Rectangle",OBJPROP_COLOR,clrRed);
  
  //Set the Object fill color
  ObjectSetInteger(0,"Rectangle",OBJPROP_FILL,clrRed);
   } 
  
}```
````

Comment: Is this your full code, looks like some is missing?

Answer (score 0):

That curly bracket closes the first `if` statement:

> // if candle 3 is a bear and candle 2 and candle 1 are both bulls..
> and if there is a gap
> if(Bear[3] and Bull[2] and Bull[1] and
> CHigh[3]<CLow[1]){ ... ) //That bracket

That same statement seems to be positioned at the global scope, since there's no `onInit()` or `onTick()` event in your code.